# Admob Android does not correlate to impressions to earnings

Tags: android, admob, impressions

I have an app currently running on the market under beta testing. Everything was working fine until I realize I stopped earning money for a couple of days.

Is this something normal due to the decrease number of impressions? Or clicks?

Why does admob ignore completely the impressions I received?

Im worried that if I promote to the store ads will not work.

I appreciate any help!! Thanks a lot!

**Screenshot of my admob report**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be three reasons for this:

1. No one is using the app and there are no impressions at all
2. All the devices on which the app is running are added as test devices
3. There is a delay in admob statistics update. This happens more than often.

**Update**: if there are impressions but no clicks there won't be any revenue till there are clicks. Most ads from admob are CPC.

Comment: If you check the screenshot there are impressions being counted. I would say its probably then number 2? Does admob automatically assign devices to be testing devices since Im in alpha? In the screenshot there are actually some impressions being received. Thanks AndroidMechanic

Comment: Sorry I meant since the app is in beta testing (not alpha)

Comment: Ah now I notice. There are impressions but no clicks. Hence no revenue. Most of the ads on admob are CPC.